# Shorewall stopped policies - routeback

Tags: linux, firewalls, iptables

Here goes a very specific question about the insides of Shorewall and Iptables in general.

Shorewall supports configuration of "Stopped Policies" using the file **routestopped**, which defines the behaviour of the firewall when Shorewall is stopped.
This works very well, but there is a parameter that we can configure in the options called "**routeback**" which according to the documentation enables the "traffic from a host back to itself".
I'm trying to understand this option and a case where it could be applied but honestly i just don't see a use case for this option.

I've checked the Iptables rules before and after applying this option, and these 3 rules are additionally added when the option **routeback** is activated (for the 3 hosts i've configured):

```
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.50.1/32 -d 192.168.50.1/32 -i eth0 -o eth0 -c 0 0 
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.50.138/32 -d 192.168.50.138/32 -i eth0 -o eth0 -c 0 0 
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.50.129/32 -d 192.168.50.129/32 -i eth0 -o eth0 -c 0 0
```

I'm not really an expert in Iptables, but i've read the documentation and it says that when the **-j** (ACTION) parameter is missing, Iptables doesn't do anything with the packet, it just adds the counters.

So this option is kind of useless in my opinion. Does anyone knows a use case for this option?

Thanks.